Can you override the default formatter for f-strings?
Reading through PEP 3101, it discusses how to subclass string.Formatter to define your own formats, but then you use it via myformatter.format(string). Is there a way to just make it work with f-strings?
E.g. I'm looking to do something like f"height = {height:.2f}" but I want my own float formatter that handles certain special cases.

F-strings are actually processed at compile time, not runtime.  you can't override the default f-string formatter is due to how Python implements f-strings at a fundamental level.

Here is something. Well, a lot actually xD

Egads. When a solution has "evil" in the first sentence, it's probably a good idea to avoid it. It was educational though.

As I mentioned in comments F-strings are actually processed at compile time, not runtime. you can't override the default f-string formatter is due to how Python implements f-strings at a fundamental level.
For example if you run
f"height = {height:.2f}"

It  effectively converts
"height = {}".format(format(height, '.2f'))

conversion happens during compilation, there's no way to "hook into" or modify this process at runtime.
What you can do is.
use decimal Module for Precision Control.
Reference - https://realpython.com/how-to-python-f-string-format-float/
from decimal import Decimal

value = Decimal('1.23456789')
print(f"Value: {value:.2f}")

Output:
Value: 1.23

Decimal implements the format method and handles the standard format specifiers like .2f.
Side Note:
We aren't really "overriding" the default formatter here - it's implementing the existing format specification protocol.
As your goal is to handle special cases for float formatting, using Decimal could solve your problem...

What's the point of Decimal there? You get the same output with the float value = 1.23456789.

@KellyBundy Decimal for precision control and deterministic behavior, which floats may lack due to their inherent binary floating-point representation. Decimal allows for arbitrary precision arithmetic. This is particularly useful when dealing with financial or scientific calculations where exact decimal representation is crucial. so i took example witrh decimal. Whenever there is need. I definitly goes for decimal rather than float. Floats are susceptible to rounding errors because they use a binary representation
